# FastAPI endpoint receiving bytes/file

Tags: python, fastapi

how can I create a FastAPI endpoint that can receive the following request example.

```py
import requests

# URL of your FastAPI endpoint
url = "http://localhost:8000/upload/?param1=temp&param2=temp"

# Path to the file you want to upload
file_path = "your_file.bin"

# Open the file and send it as binary data in the request
with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
    response = requests.post(url, data=file.read())

# Print the response from the server
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

I've already checked [Tutorial: Request Files](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/), but this doesn't look to be what I am looking for.

If I use `File` or `UploadFile`, then the client request would be something like:

```
# Files to be uploaded
files = {
    'data': ('your_file.bin', open('your_file.bin', 'rb'))
}

# Send the POST request with files
response = requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers, files=files)
```

but that is not the same thing.

These are the signatures I've tried so far but none of them works with the way I want the client to upload:

```py
@router.post(
    '/upload/',
    status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
)
def upload_binary(param1: str, param2: str, data: bytes)
```

This one I got 422 Unprocessable Entity

```py
@router.post(
    '/upload/',
    status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
)
def upload_binary(param1: str, param2: str, data: Annotated[bytes, File()])
```

Also 422 Unprocessable Entity

```py
@router.post(
    '/upload/',
    status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
)
def upload_binary(param1: str, param2: str, data: UploadFile)
```

Also 422, probably because the FastAPI server is expecting form data.

Comment: You talk about configuring a Fastapi endpoint and you show us code about fetching an endpoint, makes no sense. Better share the fastapi endpoint code you have

Comment: @azro , yes, I posted the way the client fetches/use an endpoint because I want to craft my receiving endpoint to accept the way the endpoint is being fetched/used. I've updated the question to give more details

Comment: So you didn't try anything ? stackoverflow isn't a coding service : you share what you've tried , the issue you have and we help to fix it

Comment: @azro, I think you can be more charitable on your takes. Anyway, I've added the things I've tried so far in more details.

Comment: FastAPI ALWAYS wants to interpret the response you get back.  You have to override that behavior with the `request` object.  See the dup link.